# Is there a non-split algebraic torus (over a finite field) satisfying the following properties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

Is there a non-split algebraic torus $T$ (over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$) satisfying the following properties?

1. $T$ is not $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-isomorphic to the direct product of algebraic tori of smaller dimensions;
2. The group $T(\mathbb{F}_{\!q})$ contains (or even isomorphic to) a large subgroup of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^m$ for some naturals $n, m > 1$.

Comment: Equivalently, does there exist a matrix $M \in GL_d (\mathbb Z)$, of finite order, not conjugate in $ GL_d (\mathbb Z)$ to a block-diagonal matrix, such that the solution set of the equation $M x \equiv q x \mod n$ in $(\mathbb Z/n)^m$ contains a subspace isomorpic to $(\mathbb Z/n)^m$?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you consider the solution set of this equation ?

Comment: Does 'large' have a precise meaning here?

Comment: @DimitriKoshelev Let $T$ be a torus of rank $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, which is split over $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$. Then $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^r}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ acts on the character group of $T$ base changed to $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$. The Galois group is cyclic of order $r$, and the character group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^d$. So we get a matrix $M \in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$ with $M^r=1$. Conversely, given a matrix  $M \in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$ with $M^r=1$, there is a torus as above. Will has translated your questions into the properties of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write what David Speyer said earlier. To add something, the $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$-points of the torus can be viewed as $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)^d$, with Frobenius acting as $q M^{-1}$, so the $\mathbb F_q$-points are solutions of $Mx = qx$, and the $n$-torsion $\mathbb F_q$-ponts are solutions of $Mx = qx$ in $(\mathbb Q/Z)^d[n] = (\mathbb Z/n)^d$.

Comment: Here is a precise question: Is there an example of an indecomposable torus $T$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $T(\mathbb{F}_q)$ isn't cyclic? It seems to be harder than I would have expected!

Comment: @LSpice, yes. I mean that the dimension $d$ of $T$ is constant with respect to $q$, but $n^m = \Theta(q^d)$ as $q \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\Id{\text{Id}}$The question is a little vague as to what large means, but I will show that, for any prime $\ell$ and any exponent $n$, the group $T(\FF_q)$ can contain $(\ZZ/\ell \ZZ)^n$. As Will Sawin writes in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416674/is-there-a-non-split-algebraic-torus-over-a-finite-field-satisfying-the-follow#comment1069203_416674), this corresponds to constructing a matrix $M$ of finite order in $GL_d(\ZZ)$ such that $M$ is not decomposable as $M_1 \oplus M_2$ and such that $M-q \Id$ has an $n$-dimensional kernel modulo $\ell$.

---

Before I do the general case, an example to show that $T(\FF_q)$ can contain $(\ZZ/2 \ZZ)^2$. Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity.  Note that we have an injection
$$\ZZ[X]/(X^6-1) \ZZ[X] \hookrightarrow \ZZ \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ$$
by $X \mapsto (1,\omega,-\omega,-1)$. Let $A \subset \ZZ \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ$ be the subring
$$\{ (\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta) : \alpha \bmod 3 \equiv \beta \bmod 1-\omega,\ \beta \bmod 2 \equiv \gamma \bmod 2,\ \gamma \bmod 3 \equiv \delta \bmod 1-\omega \}$$
of $\ZZ \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ[\omega] \oplus \ZZ$.
Then $A$ is an indecomposable $\ZZ[X]/(X^6-1)\ZZ[X]$-module and, as a $\ZZ$-module, $A \cong \ZZ^6$. So the action of $X$ on $A$ gives a $6 \times 6$ integer matrix $M$ whose $6$-th power is $1$, and which can't be put in block diagonal form.

Now, let $q$ be any odd prime; we count solutions of $Mx = qx$ in $A/2A$. Of course, this is just the same as $Mx=x$.

We have
$$A/2A = \FF_2 \times (\text{nilpotent extension of $\FF_4$}) \times \FF_2$$
and $M$ acts on $A/2A$ by $(1,\omega, 1)$. The point is that the condition modulo $1-\omega$ disappears modulo $2$.

Then the $1$-eigenspace of $M$ is two dimensional.

---

Now, we need to do the general case. The notation is awful, I'm afraid.

For any positive integer $d$, let $\zeta_d$ be a primitive $d$-th root of unity. Then $\ZZ[X]/(X^r-1) \ZZ[X]$ injects into the ring $\prod_{d|r} \ZZ[\zeta_d]$. I'll write $(\alpha_d)_{d|r}$ for coordinates on the product $\ZZ[\zeta_d]$. Let $p^k s$ be a divisor of $r$ with $k>1$ and $p$ not dividing $s$. Then, on the image of $\ZZ[X]/(X^r-1) \ZZ[X]$, we have $\alpha_{p^{k-1} s} \bmod \langle 1-\zeta_{p^{k-1}}, p \rangle \equiv \alpha_{p^k s} \bmod \langle 1-\zeta_{p^{k}}, p \rangle$.

Let $E$ be any set of pairs of the form $(p^{k-1} s, p^k s)$ for $p^k s| r$ and  $p$ not dividing $s$. Let $A$ be the subring of $\prod_{d|r} \ZZ[\zeta_d]$ where we impose that $\alpha_{p^{k-1} s}  \bmod \langle p,1-\zeta_{p^{k-1}} \rangle \equiv \alpha_{p^k s} \bmod \langle p,1-\zeta_{p^k}\rangle$ for $(p^{k-1} s, p^k s) \in E$. Then $A$ is a $\ZZ[X]/(X^r-1) \ZZ[X]$-module. If the graph with edge set $E$ is connected, then $A$ is not a direct sum. So, for any such connected subgraph $E$, we get an $r \times r$ matrix with $M^r = 1$ which is not a direct sum.

In particular, take $r = p \ell^{n-1}$ for some auxilliary prime $p \neq \ell$. Let $E$ be the set of pairs of the form $(\ell^i, p \ell^i)$, $0 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $(p \ell^{j-1}, p \ell^j)$ for $1 \leq j \leq n-1$.

We want to understand $A/\ell A$. We can localize $p$ first, which make the conditions modulo $\langle p,1-\zeta_{p^k} \rangle$ vanish. So $A[p^{-1}] \cong \bigoplus_{j=0}^{n-1} \ZZ[\zeta_{\ell^j}] \oplus (\text{something else})$ and then $A/\ell A \cong A[p^{-1}]/\ell A[p^{-1}] \cong \bigoplus_{j=0}^{n-1} \ZZ[\zeta_{\ell^j}]/\ell \ZZ[\zeta_{\ell^j}] \oplus (\text{something else})/\ell(\text{something else})$.

Then each $\ZZ[\zeta_{\ell^j}]/\ell \ZZ[\zeta_{\ell^j}]$ gives a one dimension $1$-eigenspace for $X$, so the space of solutions to $Mx = x \bmod \ell$ is at least $n$-dimensional. Taking $q$ to be a prime $\equiv 1 \bmod \ell$, we see that $T(\FF_q)$ can contain $(\ZZ/\ell \ZZ)^n$.

Comment: The claim $A /\ell A = \mathbb F_\ell^n \oplus \mathbb F_\ell[\zeta_p]$ seems wrong to me - doesn't it have rank $p \ell^{n-1}$?

Comment: Oh, you are right. And in my example, it shouldn't be $A/2 A = \FF_2 \oplus \FF_2 \oplus \FF_4$, it should be something like $A/2 A = \FF_2 \oplus \FF_2 \oplus \FF_4[x]/(x^2-1)$. I'll write something less precise.

Comment: I think this is still not quite right, but I get what you're trying to do now: I think the right formula is it's $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb Z[\zeta_{\ell^i} ]/\ell $ plus another summand (which is at iterative extension of $\mathbb F_\ell[\zeta_p]s$). Each of the first $n$ summands has at least one eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, giving an $n$-dimensional space in total.

Comment: Thanks. See if it looks better now.

Comment: What does "$\alpha \bmod 3 \equiv \beta \bmod 1 - \omega$" mean?

Comment: We have maps $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] \to \mathbb{Z}[\omega]/(1-\omega) \mathbb{Z}[\omega] \cong \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$. We want the image of $\alpha$ under the first map to match the image of $\beta$ under the second map. (There must be a better way to write this briefly...)